# SSH: How to disable weak ciphers?

Tags: ssh, encryption

Security team of my organization told us to disable weak ciphers due to they issue weak keys.

```
  arcfour
  arcfour128
  arcfour256
```

But I tried looking for these ciphers in ssh_config and sshd_config file but found them commented.

```
 grep arcfour *
ssh_config:#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

Where else I should check to disable these ciphers from SSH?

Comment: for SSH server it will be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and for the SSH client it will be in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  You want to look for the `Cipher` line in each, and for example have just `Cipher aes256-ctr` specified.  Then restart SSH via `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` or via the equivalent systemd command.

Comment: you want to become knowledgeable about all the parameters in `sshd_config` if you really care about SSH security, otherwise it can be all security theater.

Comment: @ron the second comment is an intriguing one, can you illustrate with an example what you intend?

Comment: the `ciphers` list is just one setting out of many for having SSH properly implemented... Protocol, PermitRootLogin, AuthorizedKeysFile, PermitEmptyPasswords, IgnoreRhosts, PermitTunnel, and so on.  You can rely on their default settings as implemented in your linux distribution, but `Ignornance is bliss only up until you have a problem`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you have no explicit list of ciphers set in `ssh_config` using the `Ciphers` keyword, then the default value, according to `man 5 ssh_config` (client-side) and `man 5 sshd_config` (server-side), is:

```
            aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,
            aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,
            chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
            aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,
            aes256-cbc,arcfour
```

Note the presence of the arcfour ciphers. So you may have to explicitly set a more restrictive value for `Ciphers`.

`ssh -Q cipher` from the client will tell you which schemes your client can support. Note that this list is not affected by the list of ciphers specified in `ssh_config`. Removing a cipher from `ssh_config` will not remove it from the output of `ssh -Q cipher`. Furthermore, using `ssh` with the `-c` option to explicitly specify a cipher will override the restricted list of ciphers that you set in `ssh_config` and possibly allow you to use a weak cipher. This is a feature that allows you to use your `ssh` client to communicate with obsolete SSH servers that do not support the newer stronger ciphers.

`nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p <port> <host>` will tell you which schemes your server supports.

Comment: Hi , I mentioned specific ciphers in ssh_config and restarted ssh service but when I did ssh -Q cipher <hostname> I am still getting all ciphers that I am getting earlier irrespective of my configuration.

Comment: I'm sorry, `ssh_config` is the client-side config, the server-side config is `sshd_config`, please try that. (It's also called `Ciphers` there.)

Comment: Yeah I know but when I grep for ciphers I found them at ssh_config so I did changes there. As production server I am not doing anything I am not sure

Comment: Note that the defaults may differ between distributions.

Comment: Seems there is no `ssh -Q` on older versions. (e.g. CentOS 6's openssh v5.3p1)

Comment: Is this still relevant todayy with Terrapin? Ref.: https://arstechnica.com/security/2023/12/hackers-can-break-ssh-channel-integrity-using-novel-data-corruption-attack/

Answer (score 48):

To disable RC4 and use secure ciphers on SSH server, hard-code the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
```

OR if you prefer not to dictate ciphers but merely want to strip out insecure ciphers, run this on the command line instead (in sudo mode):

```
sshd -T | grep ciphers | sed -e "s/\(3des-cbc\|aes128-cbc\|aes192-cbc\|aes256-cbc\|arcfour\|arcfour128\|arcfour256\|blowfish-cbc\|cast128-cbc\|rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\)\,\?//g" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

You can check ciphers currently used by your server with:

```
sudo sshd -T | grep ciphers | perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' | sort -u
```

Make sure your ssh client can use these ciphers, run

```
ssh -Q cipher | sort -u
```

to see the list.

You can also instruct your SSH client to negotiate only secure ciphers with remote servers. In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` set:

```
Host *
    ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
```

Above snippets come from [here](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html)
To test your server's settings you can use [ssh-audit](https://github.com/arthepsy/ssh-audit)

Comment: I had to use `sshd -T -C user=root` instead of just `sshd -T`, also cut out the initial word with `sudo sshd -T -C user=root | grep ciphers |cut -d " " -f2- | perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' | sort -u
`

Comment: onleine to check if all ciphers are in your system: `for i in $(sudo sshd -T -C user=root | grep ciphers |cut -d " " -f2- | perl -pe 's/,/ /g'); do echo '##'check $i; ssh -Q cipher | grep $i; done
`

Comment: Newer ssh-audit: https://github.com/jtesta/ssh-audit

Answer (score 38):

The problem with explicitly specifying a cipher list is that you must manually add new ciphers as they come out.  Instead, simply list the ciphers you want to remove, prepending the list (not each individual cipher) with a '-' character.  So in this case, the Ciphers line should read:

```
Ciphers -arcfour*
```

Or if you prefer:

```
Ciphers -arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
```

From the sshd_config man page on the **Ciphers** option ([since OpenSSH 7.5, released 2017-03-20](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.5)):

> If the specified value begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified ciphers will be appended to the default set instead of replacing them.  If the specified value begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified ciphers (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set instead of replacing them.

This also applies to the **KexAlgorithms** and **MACs** options.

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 60: Bad SSH2 cipher spec '-arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256'.` Getting this error what may be the reason

Comment: Although I would love having this feature, I believe the `-` prefix is not supported anymore and that's the reason of the error @AbhinavKinagi is getting. In fact, check:

```bash
man sshd_config
```

and you'll see:

*Specifies the ciphers allowed.  Multiple ciphers must be comma-separated.  If the specified value begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified ciphers will be appended to the default set instead of replacing them.*

Answer (score 6):

How to disable a weak ssh cipher,100% working tested on Fedora 29.
The problem:
Nessus report my samba4 server use not strong ciphers aes256-cbc and aes128-cbc.
So I put those lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

Et voilà!..it still use the cbc cipher because this command work :(

```
ssh -c aes256-cbc samba4
```

So I check the useful systemd and I discover sshd service is using another file for ciphers

```
/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config
```

Backup the file for safety

```
cp /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config     /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config.old
```

Edit it,and remove the cbc cipher.
Restart the service

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

And finally test,works fine..cbc disabled.

```
ssh -c aes256-cbc samba4
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.0.48 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
```

Answer (score 4):

enable/disable cipher need to add/remove it in file /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
After edit this file the service must be reloaded

```
systemctl reload sshd
/etc/init.d/sshd reload
```

Then,running this command from the client will tell you which schemes support

```
ssh -Q cipher
```

To check if arcfour cipher is enabled or not on the server
run this command

```
ssh localhost -c arcfour
```

To check if arcfour128 cipher is enabled or not on the server,run this command

```
ssh localhost -c arcfour128
```

Comment: This step was missing in above answers

Answer (score 0):

> SSH: How to disable weak ciphers?
>
> Asked 4 years ago

What you ask is found in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

The file below is that, taken from RHEL 7.9 and configured to *STIG*, as of this date their latest version is 2.8.  They have *called out* weak ssh ciphers and request they not be used... as such you are left with what is specified for `Ciphers` and `MACs`.

Per a web search: *problem with cbc cipher*

> The problem with CBC mode is that the decryption of blocks is dependant on the previous ciphertext block. This means attackers can manipulate the decryption of a block by tampering with the previous block using the commutative property of XOR.Oct 16, 2019.  CBC Mode is Malleable. Don't trust it for Authentication ...

All that sort of stuff is over my head so I can't vouch for how accurate or within context it all is all I know is *they* say it's bad.

Therefore the **aes###-cbc** ciphers are removed and only the **aes###-ctr** ciphers are used.  To completely answer your question, use only `aes256-ctr` and `hmac-sha2-512` as anything else would be *weaker*.

```
#  This is from RHEL 7.9 x86-64
#
#  $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $
#  If you want to change the port on a SELinux system
#  semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#


PermitEmptyPasswords                       no

PermitUserEnvironment                      no

HostbasedAuthentication                    no

Ciphers                                    aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr

ClientAliveInterval                        0

#   ** depercated **
RhostsRSAAuthentication                    no

ClientAliveCountMax                        3

IgnoreRhosts                               yes

PrintLastLog                               yes

PermitRootLogin                            no

IgnoreUserKnownHosts                       yes

Protocol                                   2

MACs                                       hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512

GSSAPIAuthentication                       no

KerberosAuthentication                     no

StrictModes                                yes

UsePrivilegeSeparation                     sandbox

Compression                                no

X11Forwarding                              yes

Port                                       22
banner                                     /etc/issue
UsePAM                                     yes
LoginGraceTime                             2m
MaxAuthTries                               6
MaxSessions                                10
TCPKeepAlive                               yes
UseLogin                                   no
AddressFamily                              any
SyslogFacility                             AUTHPRIV
PubkeyAuthentication                       yes
SyslogFacility                             AUTH
LogLevel                                   INFO
PrintMotd                                  yes
PermitTunnel                               no
ShowPatchLevel                             no
UseDNS                                     yes

#ListenAddress                             0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress                             ::
#RekeyLimit default none

PasswordAuthentication                     yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication            no

KerberosOrLocalPasswd                      yes
KerberosTicketCleanup                      yes
KerberosGetAFSToken                        no
KerberosUseKuserok                         yes

GSSAPICleanupCredentials                   no
GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck                  yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange                          no
GSSAPIEnablek5users                        no

AllowAgentForwarding                       yes
AllowTcpForwarding                         yes
GatewayPorts                               no

X11DisplayOffset                           10
X11UseLocalhost                            yes
PermitTTY                                  yes

PidFile                                    /var/run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups                                10:30:100
ChrootDirectory                            none
VersionAddendum                            none

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key


# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys

AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: SSH always uses a MAC (standardly HMAC, OpenSSH also UMAC) with ciphers that don't do their own authentication (standardly AES-GCM, OpenSSH also ChaCha+Poly), so malleability isn't a problem, but if it were, CTR is just as badly (though somewhat differently) malleable than CBC