# How to specify what MAC, cipher and key exchange openssh should use when generating the key?

Tags: ssh

I am learning openssh and I found that the fundamental of openssh has 3 components.

1. Cipher - to encrypt the data
2. Message Authentication Code (MAC) - to ensure data integrity that is data is not changed while it was doing a journey to the end user.
3. Key exchange -  It is used for session  key exchange.

Questions:

1. Is there any other important part for configuration in openssh?
2. While generating the openssh key, how I do I tell what cipher, MAC and key exchange it should use?

Comment: Why do you think those components are set while generating an OpenSSH key?

Comment: If I want higher security then I might disable weak ciphers that means I can even make it custom to choose only the highest security - Cipher, MAC and key exchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH: How to disable weak ciphers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333728/ssh-how-to-disable-weak-ciphers) (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410252/70524, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511260/70524)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any other important part for configuration in openssh?

Yes. There is a fourth major part of the SSH protocol: *authentication*.

The keys you manually generate with `ssh-keygen` (or equivalent) are used for authentication only, and have no effect at all on the three protocol elements you listed. And while those three elements are functionally symmetric, authentication can be different for each direction.

Thus, on a client, you optionally generate one or more key(s) each using a particular algorithm aka 'type' `-t` (RSA, DSA -- formerly, ECDSA, Ed25519), while you configure or default the algorithm(s) you will accept from the server. And depending on the server, the client (only!) may use other authentication methods like password (often) or GSS (rarely) instead of (any of) the publickey algorithms.

Conversely, on a server, you *can* generate key(s) for particular algorithms, but in practice most servers automatically generate *all* key types, and provide whichever one(s) the client(s) request. And you configure or default the algorithms the client's key can use, as well as any non-publickey methods.

> While generating the openssh key, how I do I tell what cipher, MAC and key exchange it should use?

You don't. You configure the *program*, not the key, for those elements. On the client, server, or both, as described in the [Q linked in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333728/ssh-how-to-disable-weak-ciphers). Although that Q doesn't note that on client side, in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/ssh_config`, you can configure either a global setting for all 'hosts' (servers), or different settings for different hosts and/or userids using the `Host` or `Match` syntax. See the man page on your system or [on the web](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config), and search for existing Qs here or maybe superuser; I know I've seen several.

Although it should be noted this won't improve security. The OpenSSH developers are pretty cautious -- some would say overly so -- and the defaults they set are already more than 'strong' enough. Obsessing over using the right magic words in your crypto config is at best a waste of time, and risks either making a mistake that *reduces* security, or more often distracting you from taking care of the things that actually *do* matter, like managing your key(s) and verifying the host authenticity.